# How to obtain a file's attributes from an Uri or InputStream

Tags: java, android, getattribute

I am developing an Android app that issues a file selector intent so that the user can select one or more files.

I receive one or more file Uri's, and can access the files via an InputStream. obtained by calling `getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(pUri)`. Using that InputStream, I can read the files.

I also would like to obtain the file's "Modification Date". Normally, I would get a File from the Uri, then use

```
Files.getFileAttributeView(path, BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
```

to get the modification date.

This method works if the file resides in the user's local app storage. However, if the file is located in External storage, such as an SD Card, the getAttribute... call triggers a file not found exception.

Is there a way, possibly by querying the content resolver, to get the file's modification date if it resides in External Storage?

Just a FYI that I DO have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Here is how I issue the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Photos"), RQS_GET_PHOTOS);
```

Here is how I process the results:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == RQS_GET_PHOTOS) {
                    //
                    // Get and process photo files
                    //         
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    Uri pUri = data.getData();
                    if (clipData == null && pUri == null) {  // Don't know if this can actually happen...
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No jpeg files selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (clipData != null) {
                        // User selected multiple files
                        pData.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            Photo photo = new Photo(getFileName(uri), uri, i);
                            pData.add(photo);
                        }
                    } else { // User only selected one file
                        Photo photo = new Photo(getFileName(pUri), pUri, 1);
                        pData.add(photo);
                    }
```

And here I am trying to get the modification date:

```
DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, iterPhoto.getUri());
                        Boolean x = df.exists();
                        Long fdate = df.lastModified();
```

But, while "df" contains data, "x" is false and fdate is 0;

Comment: If you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for the `Uri` representing the document. Then, you can [call `lastModified()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#lastModified()) to attempt to get the last-modified timestamp. I say "attempt" because that data may or may not exist, depending on where the user picks the content from.

Comment: OK, so I did this: `DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri)` , df does contain data (not null), but `df.exists()` returns false, so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You might consider editing your question to include a [mcve] showing how you are getting the `Uri` and how you are using `fromSingleUri()`.

Comment: I have updated the OP with the relevant info.

Comment: Is this all in the scope of a single activity and process? Or are you passing `Uri` values between activities, or trying to persist the `Uri` to disk?

Comment: All in one activity. Not trying to persist the Uris

Comment: I am assuming that `iterPhoto.getUri()` is the same `Uri` seen in `new Photo(getFileName(pUri), pUri, 1)`. If so... that all looks good, so I am not quite certain where things are going wrong. See If you can access any other data from the `DocumentFile`, like `getName()`.

Comment: OK. One thing I neglected to add is that this is running under Chrome OS.

I tried selecting a file from Google Drive, and everything works as expected.

I suspect this is a Chrome OS bug, as it doesnt work when the file is ion External storage. Will submit a bug report.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that may easily have an impact. You might also consider running a test on a more conventional Android environment, if you have one handy.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the assistance! Will update this when/if I get a response to my bug report.